# ScrollView Programmatic Scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to make a .xml file in which there is a scrollview which I can essentially 'spin' and have it select a random item in the list.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this and keep it visually spinning; I don't want it to just select a random item and then print it to the screen...

Comment: I have looked elsewhere in this forum and it appears that noone else has been trying to the same thing graphically as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScrollView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Have a look at :

```
void fling(int velocityY)

final void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy);

final void smoothScrollTo(int x, int y);
```